# AsciiIo instance being null

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I am using AsciiIo to create a file. I have verified that I've got full permission to the folder, however, AsciiIo instance keeps being null. I have also verified that it is running on the server (having called from set in the properties). The same code works fine if I test it in a Job though.

```
new FileIOPermission(filename,#io_write).assert();

asciiIo = new AsciiIo(filename,#io_write); //right here, it returns null
```

Has anyone faced the same issue? Can anyone suggest a way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AOS Service user` must have access to the file (is code is running on the server).